# What might make context.redirectToPage behavior different

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have two buttons in different custom controls which within their onclick events call context.redirectToPage(). In one instance, this causes an HTTP redirect (HTTP status of 302) to the expected URL (i.e. header Location = http://frontend.company.com/path/to/file.nsf/myXpages.xsp?documentId=C699C5D6E81721EA85257A2F00683319&openDocument). In the other instance, it returns a  tag like this:

```
<script>window.location.href='http://backend.company.com:81/path/to/file.nsf/myXpage.xsp?documentId=C699C5D6E81721EA85257A2F00683319&openDocument'</script>
```

Both instances have submit=true, refresh=complete and immediate=true. Both have client-side scripts which execute correctly and a few lines of SSJS that execute before the redirect call. The only difference that I can conceive that might be causing this is that the button which returns the script is within an (xe:dialog).

The astute among you will notice why this is a problem for me as our Domino server is behind a reverse proxy. Mere mortals do not have direct access to Domino and so the URL generated in the script tag will not work.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get the preferred behavior of a 302 redirect from the second button, or even a way to get it to use the correct URL? Or even shed some light on why the behavior would be different?

Thanks,

Rich

EDIT: code for button that generates script tag for context.redirect():

```
<xp:button
                id="errorReloadButton"
                value="Reload Page">

                <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:whichButton == "reload"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                <xp:eventHandler
                    event="onclick"
                    submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete"
                    immediate="true">
                    <xp:this.action>
                        <xp:actionGroup>

                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script><! [CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.remove("errors");
var c = getComponent("errorDialog")
c.hide();
var redirectTarget = view.getPageName() + '?documentId=' + compositeData.docID + '&openDocument';
context.redirectToPage(redirectTarget,true);
}]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                        </xp:actionGroup>
                    </xp:this.action>
                    <xp:this.script>
                        <xp:executeClientScript>
                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[setClean("#{javascript:compositeData.docID}");
XSP._setDirty(false,"");]]></xp:this.script>
                        </xp:executeClientScript>
                    </xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
```

EDIT 2: source for button that correctly forces a 302 redirect:

```
<xp:button
        id="cancelButton"
        value="Cancel"
        rendered="#{javascript:compositeData.documentDataSource.isEditable()}">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete"
            onError="handleError(arguments[0],arguments[1])"
            immediate="true">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:actionGroup>

                    <xp:executeScript>
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var xdoc:NotesXspDocument = compositeData.documentDataSource;
if(xdoc.isNewNote()){  
return;
}
var doc:NotesDocument = xdoc.getDocument(false);
/* more code here, not relevant to this */
var docid = doc.getUniversalID();
context.redirectToPage(view.getPageName() + '?documentId=' + docid + '&openDocument')}]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:executeScript>
                </xp:actionGroup>
            </xp:this.action>



            <xp:this.script>
                <xp:executeClientScript>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[setClean("#{javascript:docId(compositeData.documentDataSource)}");
if(#{javascript:compositeData.documentDataSource.isNewNote()}){
popPageStack();
return false;
}]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeClientScript>
            </xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

Comment: I suppose you talk about two different databases. Look into xsp.properties for param xsp.redirect, which controls redirect. More info google or here: http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/page.xsp?documentId=00D7DC9F868D7F38C12579300051C03C&action=openDocument

Comment: no, this is all in one database, actually on the same xpage, though in different custom controls. In one case its generating the 302 and another it is returning a script tag.

Comment: Embed sources for both buttons, their events must differ :-)

Comment: redirectToPage: button 1 -> (url,true), button 2 -> (url). According to docs (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc%2Fwpd_previewing_running_open.html), it possibly negates default value - param I mentioned...

Comment: Actually, that second parameter was just added as part of the debugging process. I have checked that removing it, or changing its value does not change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for fixing your problems: You could hard code the redirection to the new URL, f.e.

```
 facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect( "http://stackoverflow.com" );
```

Or you have to modify the the HTTP response with your reverse proxy.

The last option is the better one, because this would affect all partial refreshs too.
There is a additional HTTP header *X-XspLocation* which contains the target URL which has to be modified.

**EDIT:**

*the script is within an (xe:dialog).* -> That's the reason. My fault, I have not read this information. Events inside a *xe:dialog* will be forced to partial refreshs, otherwise they would not work "inside the dialog". This affects all redirects, they will always return a Javascript and a *X-XspLocation* header with the target.

In most cases the returned Javascript will not be executed, because of the header in the response, wich is parsed earlier (and forces a redirection).

As I written above, the best approach is to change the reverse proxy configuration. Alternativly you could change the server to use the external name. Or return the external address in the button code.

Comment: Just tried replacing the call to context.redirectToPage() with faces.getExternalContext().redirect() but with similar results, also generating a script tag.

Comment: @RichardIrwin: Can you please post the button codes to your question?

Comment: Well that's just unfortunate then...  I was unable to get the proxy server to fix URLs inside the body of the script tag (mod_proxy_html seems to just modify URLs in the src attribute, but maybe I just couldn't find the right setting). My work-around was to replace the context.redirectToPage() with an onComplete client-side script of my own on the event handler, using the window.location.path to allow me to use server-relative URLs.